# Inline form editing on client side

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins, inline-editing

I see some web sites use dynamic forms(I am not sure about how to call them!) to edit a group of data. For example: there is a group of data such as name, last name, city, country.etc. when user clicks on EDIT button, instead of doing postback, a form, consisisting of 2 textboxes + 2 comboboxes, dynamically opens to edit,And then when you click on Save button, edit form disappears, and all data updates..

Now, I know what happens over here is using Ajax for server calls and some javascript for dom manipulation.. I even found some jquery plugins for textbox editing.. However, I could not found anything for full implementation of form fields. Therefore I have  implemented it on asp.net by jquery ajax calls and dom manipulation manually. here is my process:

1) when Edit button clicked: Make a ajax call to server to retrieve necessary formedit.aspx
2) it returns editable form fields with values assigned.
3) when Save button clicked: make ajax call to server to retrieve formupdateprocess.aspx page. it basically do the database updates and then return necessary DOM snipplet (...) to insert current page..

well ıt works but MY PROBLEM, is performance.. Result seems  slower than samples I see in other sites.:((

IS there anything that I dont know? a better way to implement this??

Comment: you know you somehow used an upside-down exclamation point instead of a lower-case "i" in the title of your post?  i've fixed it...

Comment: @Kip: +1 for sharp eyes.

Comment: @b3: Thanks. Looking back on the edit history, though, the funny thing is that it wasn't actually an upside down exclamation point, but the infamous Turkish dotted capital "i". Maybe the author made a typo on a Turkish keyboard? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the edit form on the client, but hidden with e.g. "style="display:none;", and then show it when the user clicks the edit button.  Loading a form from the server in this event is very costly performance wise.

This is a very basic example and doesn't consider positioning the edit form etc.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#showEdit").click(function () {
                $("#editForm").css("display", "block");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="editForm" style="display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 999;">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="surnameInput">Surname:</label>
            <input id="surnameInput" type="text" />
            <label for="firstNameInput">Surname:</label>
            <input id="firstNameInput" type="text" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <input id="showEdit" type="button" value="Edit" />
</body>
```

This does mean your main page will have to carry the edit field values from first load, but very often that is a small price to pay, because the user accepts a wait at that time, not when they click a button.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jQGrid in the past with ASP.NET (MVC doesn't support GridViews).

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

and demos at
http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
(Check out the Row Editing ones).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but have you looked at [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin which allows you to edit inline content?

And here is a [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax), and the tutorial code with [some improvements](http://yelotofu.com/labs/jquery/snippets/inlineEdit/demo_final.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is done if you are like me who loathes using plugins now and again.

The HTML:

```
<div id="pesa"><p>PERSONAL INFORMATION</p>
<ul>
    EMAIL:<li class="editable">email</li>
    NAME:<li class="editable">name</li>
    TELLPHONE:<li class="editable">tel</li>
    COUNTRY:<li class="editable">country</li>
    CITY:<li class="editable">city</li>
</ul>
```

Then the CSS to cool things up:

```
 #pesa a{
 color: #000;
 }

#pesa a:hover{
 color: #;
 }


  #pesa a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 }

  h1{
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

 h2{
 font-size: 20px;
  }


  .editHover{
  background-color: #E8F3FF;
   }

  .editBox{
   width: 326px;
 min-height: 20px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #E8F3FF;
  }

  #pesa ul{
  list-style: none;
  }

  #pesa li{
  width: 330px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 5px;
 }

 li.noPad{
 padding: 0;
 width: 360px;
}

  #pesa form{
 width: 100%;
}

.btnSave, .btnCancel{
 padding: 6px 30px 6px 75px;
 }

 .block{
 float: left;
 margin: 20px 0;
 }
```

Then the JavaScript:

```
              $(document).ready(function() 
        {
var oldText, newText;
$(".editable").hover(
    function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("editHover");
    }, 
    function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("editHover");
    }
);

$(".editable").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);


$(".btnSave").live("click", 
                function()
                {
                    newText = $(this).siblings("form")
                                     .children(".editBox")
                                     .val().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

                    $(this).parent()
                           .html(newText)
                           .removeClass("noPad")
                           .bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
                }
                ); 

$(".btnDiscard").live("click", 
                function()
                {
                    $(this).parent()
                           .html(oldText)
                           .removeClass("noPad")
                           .bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
                }
                ); 

function replaceHTML()
                {
                    oldText = $(this).html()
                                     .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                    $(this).addClass("noPad")
                           .html("")
                           .html("<form><input type=\"text\" class=\"editBox\" value=\"" + oldText + "\" /> </form><a href=\"#\" class=\"btnSave\">Save changes</a> <a href=\"#\" class=\"btnDiscard\">Discard changes</a>")
                           .unbind('dblclick', replaceHTML);

                }
  }
  );
```

So when someone hovers over the li items it turns blue just some colour to let the user know they can edit. When they double-click using the `dblclick` event, a form shows up with the value of the `<li>` item, just check the code. When they edit in the form and save, the form is removed and a list with the new `htmlvalue` is placed. You can then use an `$ajax` method to send the variables to the server side for processing.