# Can't populate update parameters from a ListView's ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview, repeater, client-side, listviewitem

I am using a ListView and would like to implement the switch from read only mode to edit mode for a ListView item on the client side. Some of this is discussed at: [Inline form editing on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578129/inline-form-editing-on-client-side)

I am trying to do this by something like:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewContactNumber" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="readonly">
            <asp:Label ID="LabelType" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            <a href="#" onclick="switchState(this,"edit");return false;">Edit</a>
        </div>
        <div class="edit">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'
                MaxLength="256"
                Columns="10"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSave" runat="server"
                Text="Save"
                OnClick="LinkButtonSave_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            <a href="#" onclick="switchState(this,"readonly");return false;">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

`switchState` is a Javascript function that simply hides/shows the `DIV`s with the *readonly* and *edit* classnames. In `LinkButtonSave_Click` I get the value from `TexBoxName` but it always contains the bound original value and not the edited value that was entered in the texbox.

- Does ASP.NET not postback the textbox value because it is in the ItemTemplate or is it something else that's causing this problem?
- Could I use a Repeater instead to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the ListView was not the source of the problem at all. I was re-databinding on Page_Load without checking if it was a postback.

Answer (score 1):

when using javascript to change state you must use ajax to update your data ::